# Offline package update for TeX Live

Tags: texlive, updating

How can I update a specific package of TeX Live (2013) on an offline computer? The packages I am going to try to update are `glossaries` and `babel`.

Comment: What kind of system are you using? Note that packages may depend on other packages. I'd simply make a rsync copy of a tlnet mirror, place the copy on a USB stick, and run the update from that.

Comment: Thanks @daleif I am on Windows 7. I was hoping for a very simple solution.

Comment: Under Linux, I move the so far existing relevant package to some other place outside of the `TeXLive` tree and unpack/copy the new version to the (designed) place, afterwards I run `texconfig rehash`. Well, under Windows, I suppose,this should work as well. Of course, you should have the new package on USB stick. From www.ctan.org packages can be obtained as `zip` files.